# Angucomplete-alt not showing dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my website I have a textarea where the user has to write the name of a group project. The idea is to use autocomplete-alt so when the users are writing the name of the group project a dropdown with the projects already created has to be displayed and help them with the autocompletation.

·Code:

-HTML:

```
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Group Project</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10"><angucomplete-alt id="groupProjectID"
                              placeholder="Search Group Projects"
                              maxlength="50"
                              pause="100"
                              selected-object=""
                              local-data=""
                              search-fields=""
                              title-field=""
                              minlength="1"
                              input-class="form-control form-control-small"
                              match-class="highlight"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

-Javascript:

```
$scope.getAllGroupProjects = function () {
        api.projects.getGroupProjects().success(function (data) {
            $scope.groupProjectsList = data;
        }).error(function (data) {
            alerts.error('Error', 'Error obtaining the group projects');
        });
    }
```

`groupProjectsList` contains all the group projects that have been created. Each `GroupProject` has two attributes: `Name` (name of the group project) and `Active` (boolean that represents if the project is currently active or not).
As you will see in the HTML code there are some attributes with no value since I'm not sure how to use them. I've been reading the documentation(https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt) but I still have problems figuring out how to use them in my case.

-Edit (SOLVED):

```
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Group Project</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10"><angucomplete-alt id="groupProjectID"
                              placeholder="Search Group Projects"
                              maxlength="50"
                              pause="100"
                              local-data="groupProjectsList"
                              search-fields="Name"
                              title-field="Name"
                              minlength="1"
                              input-class="form-control form-control-small"
                              match-class="highlight"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide data to your directive.

Seeing the demos I think you should set

```
local-data="groupProjectsList"
```

If this doesn't work, please share a plunker

Comment: Thanks for your help, I edited my question in order to reflect the solution.